# Find most recurrent sequence in multiple lists

Tags: dart

The goal is to find all the sequences of numbers and list the most recurrent ones

```
list1: [10, 1, 2, 55, 14, 6, 11, 25, 125, 200]
list2 : [6, 77, 36, 11, 1, 2, 55, 125, 15, 20]
list3 : [99, 7, 6, 1, 2, 55, 125, 15, 42,68]
.....
listN : [1, 2, 55, 125, 15, 42,68, 9, 87, 16]
```

the output should be
`[1, 2, 55] : 4 times`

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem? Show us your code and we can, hopefully, help you.

Comment: If you narrow the scope to a fixed length like 3 items, the problem is drastically more computationally feasible (through brute force counting).  Without such a bound, it'd require some clever Trie algorithm or something.